# Speeding up a WolframLanguageData query

Tags: performance-tuning, curated-data

I've seen suggestions that speed up WL code by 1000s - I may not understand them...

I noticed the `WolframLanguageData` function the other day and thought it would be interesting to see what functions SW thought were adequate for the v1 release.

I interrupted my first `Select` attempt after a minute or two suspecting I had messed up:

```
Select[WolframLanguageData[#, "VersionIntroduced"] == 1 &][
 WolframLanguageData[]]
```

but the following code indicates that my `Select` query would take well over 10 mins on my machine:

```
WolframLanguageData[#, "VersionIntroduced"] & /@ 
  RandomSample[WolframLanguageData[], 10] // Timing
(* {1.55092, {1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 9, 11, 3, 11.2}} *)
```

I guess I'm phoning home to the data repositories but it seems to take a lot more time than I would expect.

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use [`EntityClass`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityClass.html) with [`EntityList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityList.html).

```
EntityList@
  EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"VersionIntroduced" -> 1}] // Short
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: certainly did - cheers.

Comment: @Joe Also of note, you can just pull the name (or other properties) if you use `EntityValue` on the `EntityClass`. That way you don’t have to pass the full `EntityList` to the API call.